# MBA 2014 13" Trackpad broken after failed Mojave installation

Tags: mojave, trackpad

The trackpad has not worked after an installation of Mojave that I had to interrupt because it was taking way too long in one of the booting or preparing phases that has an apple logo and a progress bar. Not sure if it was the actual installation of the OS, or an installation of a security update right after that I "had to" interrupt by pressing the power button. The trackpad had worked flawlessly for years on High Sierra.

I have had some success in bringing the pad alive by resetting SMC or NVRAM but now even that doesn't seem to help. If I get it back alive, it will die again after putting the mac to sleep and waking up.

Hopefully wondering if I messed up a firmware/EFI update by interrupting it? And it could be fixed by waiting for a new 122.0+ update?

**the trackpad comes alive if I let macbook go to sleep with the screen up, and wake it up by clicking the trackpad. Weird!**

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It may help to reinstall macOS using Internet Recovery (https://support.apple.com/HT201314 - note that a different version than Mojave may get installed, see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904#exceptions). Back up your Mac first, then reinstall macOS. While setting macOS up, you can choose to recover your files and applications from a backup using Migration Assistant (https://support.apple.com/HT204904).